# Proper way to include C code from directories other than the current directory

Tags: c, compilation, clang

I have two directories, `sorting` and `searching` (children of the same directory),  that have `.c` source files and `.h` header files:

```
mbp:c $ ls sorting
array_tools.c       bubble_sort.c       insertion_sort.c    main            selection_sort.c
array_tools.h       bubble_sort.h       insertion_sort.h    main.c          selection_sort.h

mbp:c $ ls searching
array_tools.c   array_tools.h   binary_search.c binary_search.h linear_search.c linear_search.h main        main.c
```

Within `searching`, I am building an executable that needs to use `insertion_sort` function, declared in `insertion_sort.h` and defined in `insertion_sort.c` inside `sorting`. The following compilation successfully produces an executable:

```
mbp:searching $ clang -Wall -pedantic -g -iquote"../sorting" -o main main.c array_tools.c binary_search.c linear_search.c ../sorting/insertion_sort.c
```

However, I would like to be able to include functions from arbitrary directories by including a header using `#include` and then providing the compiler with the search path. Do I need to precompile the `.c` files to `.o` files beforehand? The `man` page for clang lists the following option:

```
-I<directory>
      Add the specified directory to the search path for include files.
```

But the following compilation fails:

```
mbp:searching $ clang -Wall -pedantic -g -I../sorting -o main main.c array_tools.c binary_search.c linear_search.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_insertion_sort", referenced from:
      _main in main-1a1af0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`main.c` has the following `include`s:

```
#include <stdio.h>          
#include <stdlib.h>         
                            
#include "linear_search.h"  
#include "binary_search.h"  
#include "array_tools.h"    
#include "insertion_sort.h"
```

I do not understand the link between header files, source files, and object files. To include a function defined in a `.c` file, is it sufficient to include the homonymous header file, given that the `.c` file is in the same directory as the header? I have read multiple answers here on SO, the `man` page for clang and a number of tutorials, but was unable to find a definitive, clear answer.

---

In response to @**spectras**:

> One by one, you give the compiler a source file to work on. For instance:
>
> ```
> cc -Wall -Ipath/to/some/headers foo.c -o foo.o
> ```

Running

```
mbp:sorting $ clang -Wall insertion_sort.c -o insertion_sort.o
```

produces the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You have two `main.c` and want to make one program?

Comment: @aschepler I have two `main.c`, but they are in different directories. I do not intend to use the other `main.c` in the compilation.

Comment: @aschepler To clarify, the compilation is being run from the `searching` directory.

Comment: Create a library.  Install it.  Use it.

Comment: Headers are text files; they don't usually define functions or variables — they only declare them.  To make the executable, you have to find the definitions — and they're often in a library which you need to specify on the command line.  The connection between headers and libraries is tenuous; they're related, but wholly distinct.  In particular, including a header says nothing about where the object code will come from — only that the object code will be provided from somewhere that matches the specification in the header.  (If the object code doesn't match the spec, all hell breaks loose!)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for the comment! "including a header says nothing about where the object code will come from" So I gather that the proposed solution is to build a library?

Comment: You can either create a library (usually easiest in the long run) or list the individual object files to be linked on the linking command line.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler +1 Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it's mixed up a bit. Let's see how one typically compiles a simple multi-file project.

One by one, you give the compiler a source file to work on. For instance:

```
cc -c -Wall -Ipath/to/some/headers foo.c -o foo.o
```

The `-c` flag tells the compiler you want an object file, so it should not run the linker.

- The compiler runs the preprocessor on the source file. Among other things, every time it sees a `#include` directive, it searches the include paths for named file and basically copy-pastes it, replacing the `#include` with the content. This is done recursively.

  This is the step where all `.h` you include get merged into the source file. We call the whole thing a translation unit.

  You can see the result of this step by using `-E` flag and inspect the result, for instance:

  ```
  cc -Wall -Ipath/to/some/headers foo.c -E -o foo.test
  ```
- Let's make this short as other steps are not relevant to your question. The compiler then creates an object file from the resulting source code. The object file contains binary version of all code and data that was in the translation unit, plus metadata that will be used to put everything together and some other stuff (like debugging info).

  You can inspect the contents of an object file using `objdump -xd foo.o`.

Note that as this is done for each source file, this means that headers get parsed and compiled again and again and again. That's the reason they should only declare stuff and not contain actual code: you would end up with that code in every object file.

Once done, you link all the object files into an executable, for instance:

```
cc foo.o bar.o baz.o -o myprogram
```

This step will gather all, resolve dependencies and write everything into an executable binary. You may also pull in external object files using `-l`, like when you do `-lrt` or `-lm`.

For instance:

- foo.c includes bar.h
- bar.h contains a declaration of function do_bar: `void do_bar(int);`
- foo.c can use it, and compiler will generate foo.o correctly
- foo.o will have placeholders and the information that it requires `do_bar`
- bar.c defines the implementation of `do_bar`.
- so bar.o will have the information “hey if anyone needs `do_bar`, I got it here”.
- linking step will replace placeholders with actual calls to `do_bar`.

Finally, when you pass multiple `.c` files to the compiled like you do in your question, the compiler does basically the same thing, only it won't generate the intermediate object files. Overall process behaves the same though.

So, what about your error?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_insertion_sort", referenced from:
      _main in main-1a1af0.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

See? It says linking step failed. That means previous step went well. The `#include` worked. It's just in the linking step, it's looking for a symbol (data or code) called `_insertion_sort`, and does not find it. That's because that symbol was declared somewhere (otherwise source using it would not have compiled), but its definition is not available. Either no source file implemented it, or the object file that contains it was not given to the linker.

=> You need to make `_insertion_sort`'s definition available. Either by adding `../sorting/insertion_sort.c` to the source lists you pass or by compiling it into an object file and passing that. Or by building it into a library so it can be shared by your two binaries (otherwise they'll each have a copy embedded).

When you get there, usually starting to use a build toolsuite such as [`CMake`](http://cmake.org/) is a good idea. It will take care of all the details for you.

Comment: Pardon if I'm missing something, but running object file creation on a single source file (no `main`) produces an error. Please see end of my question for details.

Comment: @AndreyPortnoy> sorry, my fault, I forgot the `-c`. It's the flag that tells the compiler not to attempt linking yet. Fixed.

Comment: The standard uses the term 'translation unit' for what you call a 'compilation unit'.  In the standard §5.1.1.1 Program structure, it sayeth: _¶1…The text of the program is kept
in units called_ source files, _(or_ preprocessing files) _in this International Standard. A
source file together with all the headers and source files included via the preprocessing
directive `#include` is known as a_ preprocessing translation unit. _After preprocessing, a
preprocessing translation unit is called a_ translation unit.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler> that's right. Thanks for noticing, fixed :)