# Compiling multiple C++ files in command line?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a tutorial right now that doesn't make it to clear on how to do this.

I have two files, int2.cpp which has my main and int1.cpp which is a function (int2 calls on int1) I know they will work but how would one type it into the command line? tutorial says `g++ int2.cpp int1.cpp -o int2.cpp`, but it says " g++ is an illegal command"

I'm using DOSbox 0.74.

I compile things with tcc sorry but it says -o isn't a command line option

Comment: Why are you using DOSbox, to compile with g++?

Comment: Answer on related question that might help you later on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684658/3212865

Comment: [This](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100419132104AABPkWs) (2nd answer) might be relevant, it suggests using `gxx` instead.

Comment: @Michael: I recommend installing and using some Linux distribution to run `g++`

Comment: That part after -o is wrong, as it is the output file, so that would overwrite your source file...

Comment: BTW the `-o int2.cpp` is very wrong, you mean `-o int2` (on Linux or POSIX) or `-o int2.exe` (on Windows and DOS).

Comment: And you really should always compile with `g++  -Wall -Wextra -g` since you want all the warnings and debug info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I compile things with tcc sorry but it says -o isn't a command line option

[TurboC++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) is an obsolete compiler (for an obsolete variant of C++); don't use it.

[TinyC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler) (e.g. the `tcc` command) is a compiler for C, not for C++.

C and C++ are *different* languages, and you want to learn at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) (since older standards of C++ are obsolete and very different, it is not worth learning them in 2017).

So get and use a [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C++11 compiler like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). BTW both are easily available on most Linux distributions (which I recommend you to use).

Of course you'll want to compile with warnings and debug information, so use
`g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with  [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/).

BTW, you probably want to compile several [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) into a single [executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable) binary. This often involves a linking step (i.e. running the [linker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) on *several* [object files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file), also using the `g++` command). Consider learning to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) (which has a lot of builtin [rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html) to help in doing that).

Comment: I updated to MinGW and am not having any more problems thankyou

Answer (score 0):

g++ is an illegal command means the compiler is not installed on your path. The syntax is (almost) right, you likely just don't have gcc installed.

```
g++ int2.cpp int1.cpp -o int2.exe
```

Comment: Okay, I can get it but I can already compile single files without it is there another way to run them? or compile, someone changed it to compiling but I think there's a difference between compiling and running(I think).

Comment: @Michael: Read more about compilation of a program made of *several* source files (technically, [translation unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))s...). You need to [*link*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) several object files into an executable. Or at least compile with the command `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g int1.cpp int2.cpp -o intprog.exe` then run `./intprog.exe` (probably also use the debugger `gdb`)

Comment: I don;t know if you can see the revision or not but I've been compiling and running code with tcc such as    tcc int2.cpp